# Cant access model that does not descend directly from ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, inheritance

I have converted a `Rails 2.3.14` project to `Rails 3.2.2`
I am having trouble with tables that dont descend directly from `ActiveRecord::Base`

I have a model defined as follows:

```
class PauaServiceTable < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.abstract_class?
       true
    end
    ..
    ..
 end
```

I have many classes that descend from this class. For example:

```
 class Lookup < PauaServiceTable
    ...
 end
```

In a Rails `console (3.3.2)` I can instantiate any table that descends directly from `Activerecord::Base` but any of the tables that inherit from `PauaServiceTable` fail with the following stack trace:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.2)
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > l=Lookup.new
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Incorrect table name '': SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM ``
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `query'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `execute'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `log'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:243:in `execute'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:211:in `execute'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:257:in `execute_and_free'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:424:in `columns'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:12:in `initialize'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `call'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `default'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `[]'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:228:in `columns'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:243:in `column_defaults'
    from /Users/george/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails322/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:479:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `new'
    from (irb):1ruby-1.8.7-p334 :002 >
```

This code worked fine in `Rails 2.3.14` but now fails after converting to `3.2.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set `@abstract_class = true` in `class PauaServiceTable`

--- EDITED

for some reason, table_name is empty, try the following:

```
class Lookup < PauaServiceTable
  set_table_name 'lookups'
end
```

I can reproduce your error with this code:

```
class PauaServiceTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.abstract_class?
    true
  end
end

class Lookup < PauaServiceTable
end
```

But, the following works:

```
class PauaServiceTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  @abstract_class = true
end

class Lookup < PauaServiceTable
end


l= Lookup.new
+----+------------+------------+
| id | created_at | updated_at |
+----+------------+------------+
|    |            |            |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: You are correct. @abstract_class=true DOES work. The code I posted was not entirely accurate. The table was TWO levels down from ActiveRecord::Base and so I needed to put the @abstract_record=true in  TWO parent classes.

Answer (score 0):

Are the `PauaServiceTable` and `Lookup` Model for a single table?

If so, then your `PauaServiceTable` Model should have the table name and the `Lookup` table should automatically get it. You can also take a look at `Single Table Inheritance` .

If not, means two models are for two tables, why `Lookup` should inherit `PauaServiceTable`? May be you need to establish a relations(`has_many`, `has_one` etc) between these two `model`s.

Comment: No I DONT want STI that is why I want the parent class to be abstract.

Answer (score 0):

For Rails 3.2.1+, I believe you want

```
class PauaServiceTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

See [ActiveRecord::Inheritance::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance/ClassMethods.html)